# Changing image src over time

Tags: android, android-studio

Im pretty new to android and I'm trying to make an imagebutton in android studio that changes images at set inervals. I tried to just use wait and put it into a different thread but that doesn't seem to work. All I want if for the image to change while also still allowing for a mp3 to be played whilst doing so.

```html
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    
                    try
                    {
                        wait(1000);
                        ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank2);
                        wait(1000);
                        ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank3);
                        wait(1000);
                        ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank4);
                        wait(1000);
                        ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank5);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {}

                }

            }
        };

        Thread myThread = new Thread(r);
        myThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
public void changeImages() {
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank1);
        }
    }, 1000);

    uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ank.setImageResource(R.drawable.shank2);
        }
    }, 2000);

    ...
}
```

Better way:

```
public void changeImages() {
    int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.shank1, R.drawable.shank2 ... }
    long delay = 1000;
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    for (int imageRes : images) {
        uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ank.setImageResource(imageRes);
            }
        }, delay);
        delay += 1000;
    }
}
```

The best way

```
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

void changeImages() {
    queue.add(R.drawable.shank1);
    queue.add(R.drawable.shank2);
    ...
    loopImages();
}

void loopImages() {
    if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                ank.setImageResource(queue.poll());
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything's working perfectly now thanks a lot for the help. also thanks for the multiple solutions Ill be sure to reference this in the future.